# Spliting line to array of words

Tags: java, regex, swing, split

I'm finding the longest and shortest word in the txt.file.
But I always take result

```
File Path: there it's ok.
The longest word: *empty*
The shortest word: *empty*
Task complete...
```

Code:

```
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String max = "", min = "BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla";
        // We take a single line
        for(String line: lines){
            // Break the next line through the regular to an array of words
            List<String> words = Arrays.asList(line.split("\\P{Punct}\\P{Space}"));
            String tempMax = Collections.max(words);
            max = max.length() < tempMax.length() ? tempMax : max;
            String tempMin = Collections.min(words);
            min = min.length() > tempMin.length() ? tempMin : min;
        }

        textArea.setText(String.format(
                "File Path: %s\n" +
                        "The longest word: %s\n" +
                        "The shortest word: %s\n" +
                        "Task complete...", fileName, max, min));
```

Give a hint)

Comment: So what's the problem ?

Comment: Try to split the string with `"[\\p{P}\\p{S}\\p{Zs}\t]+"`. Please define the "word" if that does not help. Maybe a better approach is to match with `"(?>\\p{L}\\p{M}*+)+(?:[-'](?>\\p{L}\\p{M}*+)+)*"`.

Comment: What have you done to find the error yourself? Starting at Javadoc for [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) you would see that the character classes are defined with a lowercase `p`. e.g. `\p{Punct}` and not `\P{Punct}`.

Comment: If you provide a sample data of input file then we can help you better.

Answer (score 2):

Problem seems to be here:

```
String tempMax = Collections.max(words);
```

[`Collections.max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-) returns the **maximum element** of the given collection.

For a `List<String>` **maximum element** will give you word that is **alphabetically** last in the list.

So for example in this list:

```
new String[] {"food", "zz", "abcdef", "zoo"}
```

It will find `"zz"` as maximum element.

Moreover your regex for splitting the wors `\\P{Punct}\\P{Space}` is incorrect.

- `\\P{Punct}\\P{Space}` means a non-punctuation word followed by a white-space.

There are some very helpful comments below your question that suggest right way to split.

At the minimum use: `[\\p{P}\\P{ZS}]+` for splitting.

Comment: A good solution would be `Collections.max(words, Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))`.

Comment: Even your answer is correct. It's not the answer to the OP question why the value of `max` and `min` are an empty string. ;-)

Comment: @SubOptimal: That depends on file content as well. Also note that OP's split regex `\\P{Punct}\\P{Space}` is incorrect as has been pointed out in comments.

Comment: Agree. There are multiple points which needs to be reviewed by the OP. Hence I asked what was already done to find the error.

Answer (score 0):

Regex pattern used is not correct and also use Comparator to get the result

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String max = "", min = "";
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
// We take a single line
for(String line: lines){
    // Break the next line through the regular to an array of words
    words.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split("[\\p{Punct}\\s]+")));
}

Comparator<String> stringComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return Integer.valueOf(o1.length()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2.length()));
    }
};

max = Collections.max(words,stringComparator);
min = Collections.min(words,stringComparator);

textArea.setText(String.format("File Path: %s\n" +"The longest word: %s\n" +"The shortest word: %s\n" +"Task complete...", fileName, max, min));
```